# JMeter reading values from JSON

Tags: json, jmeter

I am testing a web service. I have to use one call to get the values that will then be used by a different call. The values are coming in from JSON. I can get them into the format [31, 35, 27] as a string. My path looks something like /platform/inspector/scan/${scanId}. What can I do with that string so that those individual values are used in the path individually during the test?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how this value comes in JSON maybe you can extract the numbers as individual values using [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor), check out [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) for some clues.

However if `[31, 35, 27]` is the absolute maximum you can get, you can get the individual values as follows:

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) somewhere **after** JSON Path PostProcessor
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to: variable, holding this `[31, 35, 27]` value (without dollar sign and braces), like `yourVar`
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `value`
   - Regular Expression: `(\d+)`
   - Match no: `-1`

You'll get variables like:

```
value_1=31
value_2=35
value_3=27
value_matchNr=3
```

[image: Regexp Tester]